# How to prevent Arduino's digital pins goes high on bootup?

Tags: arduino, digital

I have done my project finally :) , but i noticed that the arduino board on startup it's some digital pins goes high for a bit time 1 seconds or little more! and this causes problem in my project because i'm using it in starting dc motor.
I forgot to mention that i have 2 relays connected with arduino and they are triggered on arduino startup or with resetting it, then my code works perfectly. I tried doing pull up resistor and pull down resistor but it seems same situation. Also tried (INPUT_PULLUP) and no result.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Do you initialize the pins at the beginning of setup with `digitalWrite(pin, LOW)`?

Comment: Yes, it solved by reverse all output values from HIGH to LOW because the relay works in active low

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when booting the arduino/connecting to a power source. Only using `digitalWrite(pin, LOW)` in `void setup()` did not work for me.
Every pin needs to be connected to a physical pull-down 10kOhm resistor in parallel to whatever you're controlling.